# Equality of Limits of Gaussian Integral

Tags: integration, gaussian-integral

Suppose I have the following equivalence for $x < y$: $$\int_{x+1}^{y+1} \exp\left(\frac{-u^2}{2}\right)du = \int_{-y+1}^{-x+1} \exp\left(\frac{-u^2}{2}\right)du$$

I know (from graphing these) that the only solution is $y = -x \quad (1)$, but I cannot rigorously prove this using the symmetry of the Gaussian integral.  Why can we make the equality $(1)$?  Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By substituting $z = -u$ and using linearity of the integral we get:

$$\begin{align*} \int_{x+1}^{y+1} \exp\left(\frac{-u^2}{2}\right)du &= \int_{-y-1}^{-x-1} \exp\left(\frac{-u^2}{2}\right)du \\ &= \int_{-y-1}^{-y+1} \exp\left(\frac{-u^2}{2}\right)du  &+ \int_{-y+1}^{-x+1} \exp\left(\frac{-u^2}{2}\right)du \\&&+ \int_{-x+1}^{-x-1} \exp\left(\frac{-u^2}{2}\right)du\end{align*}$$

By your equivalence it follows:

$$\int_{-x-1}^{-x+1} \exp\left(\frac{-u^2}{2}\right)du = \int_{-y-1}^{-y+1} \exp\left(\frac{-u^2}{2}\right)du$$

Now define a function $$F(x) = \int_{-x-1}^{-x+1} \exp\left(\frac{-u^2}{2}\right)du$$

and you will see that this function is increasing on $(-\infty,0]$ and decreasing on $[0,\infty)$, so the equation $$F(x) = F(y)$$ can have at most two solutions. One is $x=y$ the other one $y = -x$ and we are done.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake in the question.  I've corrected it now.  I needed the $+1$ in the limits

Comment: @qp212223 edited my answer